# Cannot getting the Current directory Path in Python (Linux)

Tags: python, linux

I was trying to execute the Program that I coded in Windows, in a Linux environment,
I was consistently getting error on the line that was supposed to Import the file from the sub-folder.

The program gives the following error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "BlackBox.py", line 26, in <module>
    from BB_Files import BB_Expand
ImportError: No module named BB_Files
```

Despite the presence of the file BB_Expand inside BB_Files folder, I am still getting the error.

I have also tried appending the path of my current directories in Python,

```
sys.path.append("/home/pe/Desktop/AES")
# Sub-Folders of AES are also accessible
sys.path.append("/home/pe/Desktop/AES/BB_Files")
```

But Still no Luck,

This is the File Structure,

```
/home/pe/Desktop/AES/Main.py
/home/pe/Desktop/AES/BB_Files
/home/pe/Desktop/AES/BB_Files/BB_Days.py
/home/pe/Desktop/AES/BB_Files/BB_Expand.py
/home/pe/Desktop/AES/BB_Files/BB_Steps.py
```

this is the output of `ls -l` command,

```
drwxrwx--x 4 pe users  4096 Oct 26 21:43 BB_Files
-rw-rw---- 1 pe users 15284 Oct 26 22:04 Main.py
```

This is some initial code in the file,

```
import sys    # sys.argv ; sys.path, sys.exit
import os
import hashlib
import struct # Interpret strings as packed binary data
import getopt # for Runtime arguments
import time
from datetime import date

# Append Paths from where the Files would be Imported.
sys.path.append("/home/pe/Desktop/AES")
# Sub-Folders of AES are also accessible
sys.path.append("/home/pe/Desktop/AES/BB_Files")
# Sub-Fodlers of BB_Files are also accessible now (Tables)
from BB_Files import BB_Expand
from BB_Files import BB_Steps
from BB_Files import BB_Days
```

This is the line giving an error,

```
from BB_Files import BB_Expand
```

The program doesn't run after this line because the Python couldn't find this Module.

But when I tried to print the path of the current directory I get nothing, have a look,

```
print("Path is:",os.path.dirname(__file__))
print("sufiyan")
```

**Output:**

```
('Path is:', '')
sufiyan
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "BlackBox.py", line 25, in <module>
    from bbfiles import bbexpand
ImportError: No module named bbfiles
```

I want to know why the path is not being printed while its printing fine in Windows. 
All i get is a black space instead of the path of the current directory.

Comment: try adding an `__init__.py` file to both folders

Comment: you mean an empty file ?

Comment: yep, this file tells python that the folder is a module, just it's presence.

Comment: from BB_Files import BB_Expand and in error you have from bbfiles import bbexpand? how the BB_Files changes into bbfiles ?

Comment: In Python by default a `from xxx import yyy` does not mean `xxx` is a directory and `yyy` is some module in that directory. Try adding an empty `__init__.py` file to `xxx` and then it those will work. Look up "packages" in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously the following line will throw an `ImportError` error

```
from BB_Files import BB_Expand 
## if you comment this the next immediate line will give you same error
```

Since this is your first attempt to import your module from a package

so, when you say

```
from <something> import <something-else>
```

means that, you are importing a `module/class/function` from a `package/module`

in your case it's a `package`, probably a file called `__init__.py` to be placed in your directory, so the `python` will consider the directory as a package.

```
## try this to get your directory name
print __file__
print "Path is:", os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

Comment: you just use `print()` notation, since you are using python3+

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an `__init__.py` file to both directories. It doesn't have to contain anything but it must exist.
When Python tries to load a module directory it first tries to load this file since it can contain additional instructions as to the loading of the module (such as the ability to import platform-dependent code from the correct file). If Python doesn't find the file it might not consider the directory as a Python module and fail to import files from it.

Read more about it in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

Answer (score 0):

Adding an empty file named `__init__.py` inside the `/home/pe/Desktop/AES/BB_Files` directory should solve the problem. Read more on [Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages).